# Is there a way to only sync up to a certain block?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, synchronization

I am planning on doing some transaction analysis on the blockchain, however, I only want to do it on a small part of the blockchain first and then run it on the full blockchain later on. I have downloaded the bitcoind client, is there any way to only sync up to a certain block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bitcoind` supports the argument `-stopatheight`, which takes the number of blocks to download before halting.

Comment: Surprising that this flag does not show up while running the `bitcoind -?` command, could you point me to some documentation I can look at?

Comment: It’s not a normal option. `bitcoind -help -help-debug`